Cython interfaces for two libraries sharing an interface for a third library
My project involves 3 dlls for each of which I am building python interfaces. Let's call them aux, libA and libB. The idea is that aux defines a python object (which I will call Point that is used by both libA and libB. In particular, I want to be able to define a class in libA (say "sender") that can provide an instance of Point which can, in turn be used as argument to a method of a class defined in libB (which I call "receiver"). To make this a little clearer, imagine a python script using these interfaces as follows:
import aux
import libA
import libB

mySender   = libA.sender()     # create a sender instance
myReceiver = libB.receiver()   # create a receiver instance

myPoint = mySender.GetPoint()  # get a Point from the sender
myReceiver.SetPoint(myPoint)   # set the receiver's Point to the instance provided by the sender

The way I have things set up right now (to be described below), I am able to build all three interfaces and write a script that can do most of what is shown above.
The problem I'm having though has to do with the last line of the above. I get an error that says something like
TypeError: Argument 'myPoint' has incorrect type (expected libB.Point, got libA.Point)
i.e. it seems like each of libA and libB exports its own version of Point whereas I was expecting mySender.GetPoint() to return an object of type aux.Point and I was expecting myReceiver.SetPoint() to expect an argument also of type aux.Point.
My interface is designed as follows:

each library has its own pair of definition (pxd) and implementation(pyx) files. (E.g. aux.pxd, aux.pyx and so on.)

In aux.pxd I have:


cdef extern from "Point.h":
    cdef cppclass cppPoint "Point":
        cppPoint() except +

and in aux.pyx I have:
cdef class Point:
    cdef cppPoint* c_Point_ptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_Point_ptr = new cppPoint()
 
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_Point_ptr


In libA.pxd I have the following (I'm leaving out some irrelevant details):

from aux cimport *

cdef extern from "libA.h":

    cdef cppclass cppSender "Sender":
        cppSender() except +
        cppPoint& GetPoint()

and in libA.pyx I have:
from cdm import *

include "aux.pyx"

cdef class sender:
    cdef cppSender* c_Sender_ptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_Sender_ptr = new cppSender()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_Sender_ptr

    def GetPoint(self):
        cdef cppPoint* thisPoint = &self.c_Sender_ptr.GetPoint()
        point = Point()
        point.c_Point_ptr = thisPoint
        return point

4.) In libB.pxd I have:
from cdm cimport *

cdef extern from "libB.h":
    cdef cppReceiver "Receiver":
        cppReceiver() except +
        void SetPoint(const cppPoint&)

and in libB.pyx I have:
from cdm import *
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref

include "aux.pyx"

cdef class receiver:
    cdef cppReceiver* c_cppReceiver_ptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.cppReceiver_ptr = new cppReceiver()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_cppReceiver_ptr

    def SetPoint(self, Point point):
        cdef cppPoint* thisPoint = point.c_Point_ptr
        self.cppReceiver_ptr.SetPoint(deref(thisPoint))

In summary, the idea is that libA's implementation of sender.GetPoint() provides a reference to a cpp object of type cppPoint. Then sender.GetPoint() takes that reference and assigns its address to the cppPoint pointer member of a python Point object and returns that Point Object to the calling environment. Then in that calling environment, receiver.SetPoint() takes that Python Point Object as an argument, and extracts the cppPoint pointer from the python Point object to provide it (dereferenced) to the SetPoint method of cppReceiver (which takes a reference to a cppPoint as its argument).
(Note: the above description is a simplification of my actual code base. I'm trying to keep things as uncluttered as possible to provide a clear description without irrelevancies. One consequence of this is there may be minor typos above that are irrelevant to the actual problem though I'm trying hard to get all the syntax right.)
As stated above, my interface for all of this builds without complaint. But when I try to use it in a script I get the kind of error mentioned above in which the script seems to think there are two kinds of Point objects, one called libA.Point and one called libB.Point whereas I was expecting them both to be of type aux.Point.

This mistake is include "aux.pyx". That's a literal textual include of the contents of aux.pyx in both libA and libB, so that they actual do define two different Point classes. cimport is correct here so just use that.

Yes, I thought this line might have something do with the problem, but when I leave it out the interface doesn't build at all. Instead I get an error about an undeclared name not buildin: Point

Then you need Point to be mentioned in your aux.pxd file

There is potential for confusion here because in my C++ source the class is "Point", so to distinguish between this and the "Point" python object I'm designating the C++ "cppPoint" as can be seen in my description above and this is included in my aux.pxd file. The "Point" python object is implemented in aux.pyx. My understanding is that Python class implementations cannot be in a pxd (definitions) file.  Am I missing something here?

Yes you want (some of) the Point Python object in the pxd file: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types

Ah yes! Got it! I read that entry in the user guide and I just wasn't seeing what it was trying to tell me. So you've answer the question for me but in the comments. Do you want to provide an actual answer? if not I may put something in for anyone who stumbles on this but I'll be sure to credit you.

I'm not feeling hugely motivated to write it up properly today so feel free to write it yourself (put it as an answer though rather than an edit to the question)

This answer comes from DavidW (see comments). The problem is solved by first removing the lines include "aux.pyx" from libA.pyx and libB.pyx which were having the effect of defining separate Point classes for each of libA and libB. Then secondly, by defining a single shared Point class by adding the lines:
 cdef class Point:
    cppPoint* c_Point_ptr

to aux.pxd which makes it possible to share the single Point python class defined in aux with both libA and libB. The implementation of Point should remain in aux.pyx but without the line cdef cppPoint* c_Point_ptr since that is already in the definition in aux.pxd.
